# An equation with multiple solutions: finding the maximum of the function of the solutions.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization, fixed-point-theorems, transcendental-equations

Possibly, this is a bad (stupid) question, but sometimes some discussion helps.

I have a fixed point equation (involving $\tanh$). I would like to derive the dependency of some function of the fixed point on some parameter $x$. Denote $z(x)$ a fixed point for the parameter $x$ and let the function be $y(z(x))$.

For sure for hyperbolic tangent there exists a region where there are three fixed points with corresponding values of $y$ e.g. $y_1, y_2, y_3$. If I just draw this dependency of $y$ on $x$ (i.e. $y(z(x))$, I will get something that looks similar to what is depicted on the picture.

Now I would love to know the value of parameter $x$ where $y$ is maximized. How do I deal with this case when there is multiplicity of fixed points (i.e. three branches of the function)? What would be your approach to tackle this problem?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Define the function $y$ to equal the maximum of the three branches (the graph will then be made of branch 3 until the rightmost vertical, then a vertical jump, continuing on branch 1.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust, this was my initial idea. But then I have a weird question: let's focus on the internal interval (with three fixed points). How to explore the $f(x) = \max y(z(x))$ function there?

Comment: I do not get why your function has three branches. Could you provide a simple version of your fixed point equation?

Comment: @mvw sure, for instance, $z = \tanh{(z x - 5)}$ let's say when parameter $x=20$ it has 3 fixed points.

Comment: As said: use $y_3$; if you can't predict that $y_3$ is the largest, use $\max(y(z_1(x)),y(z_2(x)),y(z_3(x)))$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, I understand that. However it can be problematic, for instance, to check for monotonicity (or second order derivative) with this $\max$ there + when the functions are also implicit ($z$ is found from the fixed point equation and for sure $z$ will be an implicit function of $x$). Or do I miss something?

Comment: The case is not much simpler for a single fixed-point, where the function is also implicit. The derivative of the maximum of three functions is the derivative of the function that achieves the maximum at that point. The maximum of three functions is monotonous if the three functions are monotonous in the respective domains where they are the largest.

Comment: Thanks, @YvesDaoust. I will try to give it more thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to recapitulate to understand this:

You have a family of functions $y_x(z)$ for $x \in X$, for example
$$
y_x(z) = \tanh(x z - 5)
$$

Here is a plot, note that the $x$ from the label is the variable $z$ from above and thus $f(x,7)$ rather means $y_7(z)$ etc.

[image: family of functions, fixed points]

The family of functions $y_x$ has an associated family of sets of fixed points 
$$
\mbox{F}_x = \{ z^* \,\left\vert\, y_x(z^*) = z^* \right. \} 
$$

In the plot $F_7$ features no fixed point in the plotted range, $F_8$ contains $\{ 0.7.., 1 \}$ and $F_{20}$ contains $\{ 0.2.., 1 \}$.

For each set $F_x$ we can define a function, which picks the maximum fixed point or returns a special value $\bot$ if $F_x$ is empty (I drop the case where $F_x$ is not empty and where no maximum element exists) 
$$
\mu(x) = \left \{
\begin{array}{cr}
\max F_x & \mbox { if } F_x \ne \emptyset \\
\bot & \mbox { if } F_x = \emptyset
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Here we would have $\mu(7) \approx -1$, $\mu(8) = \mu(20) = 1$.

You are interested in those $x \in X$ which result in the largest fixed point $z^*$ selected over all sets $F_x$.

It seems you want to calculate
$$
\operatorname*{arg\,max}_{x \in X} \mu(x) \quad (*)
$$

In our example with $X = \{ 7, 8, 20 \}$ it would be
$$
\operatorname*{arg\,max}_{x \in X} \mu(x) = \{ 8, 20 \}
$$

So much to have a framework for talking.

You probably want to have a method which calculates $(*)$ for 
a given family of function $y_x$. This seams hard because even the mapping $x \mapsto F_x$ is usually hard to determine for individual $x$ for general $y_x$. 
The resulting subject $\mu$ of argument maximization is thus hard too.

So if you can not exploit special properties of $y_x$ I seems like one ends up with some kind of search over $X$.

Comment: Thank you @mvw. My problem is even a bit harder. I first find fixed point $z_x = \tanh{(z_x x - 5)}$, so the set $F_x = \{z^* \vert z^* = \tanh{(z^* x - 5)}\}$ and then on top I apply function $y(\cdot)$. So for each fixed point $z$ from the set $F_x$ I calculate $y(z)$. And then $\mu(x) = \max_{z_x \in F_x} y(z_x)$. Seems like my question was too confusing)